# Permanently remove interface ipv6 address

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, virtualbox, static-ip

I am running Ubuntu servers 16.04.5 LTS in virtual box. The servers are connected with an internal network to which want to assigne an IPv6 address range `fd01:2345:6789:abcd::/64`. The interface connected to this internal network is `enp0s8`.
To the interface `enp0s8` on `Server 1` I have assigned the address `fd01:2345:6789:abcd::1/64`, and it also has another IPv6 address which I have not assigned myself which is `fe80::a00:27ff:fe64:5805/64`.

```
 enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:64:58:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fd01:2345:6789:abcd::1/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe64:5805/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I would like to permanently remove the address `fe80::a00:27ff:fe64:5805/64`, but if I remove it with `sudo ip addr del fe80::a00:27ff:fe64:5805/64 dev enp0s8`, after rebooting the address is there again.
I have checked if there is dhcp running but it does not seem to be on the `enp0s8` interface:

```
:~$ ps -aux | grep dhcp
root       827  0.0  0.2   6012  2544 ?        Ss   11:28   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.enp0s3.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.enp0s3.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.enp0s3.leases enp0s3
```

This is how I have configured `enp0s8` in `/etc/network/interface`:

```
# The local intnet1 network interface
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet6 static
    address fd01:2345:6789:abcd::1/64
    network fd01:2345:6789:abcd::
```

I encounter the same problem also on the other virtual machine.
How can I permanently remove the IPv6 address I don't want?

Comment: Your ULA address of `fd01:2345:6789:abcd::1/64` is obviously not using the required random 40-bit Global ID.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ron. I m just testing localy on VMs for school assignment, and that is the address I m required to use for the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The addresses in fe80::/10 subnet are IPv6 LINK-LOCAL addresses and ARE REQUIRED for correct IPv6 operation (they are for example used for neighbor discovery).

You probably cannot remove it and definitely SHOULD NOT remove it if you want to have operational IPv6.